# How to solve the following quadratic word problem given a quadratic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, word-problem

The height of a ball $(h)$ feet, after $s$ seconds is modeled by the equation: $$h=-16t^2+40t-6$$ How many seconds does it take for the ball ($t$) reach its maximum height?
First thing I did was turn the negatives into positive. And also factored it 
$$h=2(8t^2 - 20t + 3)$$
But then I couldn't find the factors that would give me $20$? How would I solve this problem?

Comment: do you know calculus?

Comment: Do you know how to complete the square? How to find the vertex of a parabola function?

Comment: I do know that I was just asking incase i didn't have a calculator or the test was calc inactive

Comment: You can't just "turn the negatives into positives". If you had an equation, say $-x^2-x-1=0$ then you could multiply both sides by $-1$ to give $x^2+x+1=-0$. But of course $-0=0$, so you have $x^2+x+1=0$. In your case, you have the equation $h=-16t^2+40t-6$. If you multiply both sides by $-1$ you get $-h=16t^2-40t+6$. You now have a formula for the negative of the height of the ball. I don't think that this is what you wanted. What I would recommend is taking out a factor of $-2$ on the right hand side of the original equation to give $h=-2(8t^2-20t+3)$.

Answer (score 3):

Don't turn the negatives into positives, but do complete the square.

$$\begin{align}
h&=-16t^2+40t-6 \\
 &= -16\left(t^2-\frac 52t\right)-6 \\
 &= -16\left(t^2-\frac 52t+\frac{25}{16}\right)-6+25 \\
 &= -16\left(t-\frac 54\right)^2+19 \\
\end{align}$$

We see the maximum happens at $t=\frac 54$ and the maximum height is $19$.

Answer (score 0):

Given the exact thing you must solve, the time for maximum height, the simplest, fastest solution is to find the vertex, using $x=\frac{-b}{2a}$, this results in $\frac{-40}{-32} = \frac{5}{4}$ seconds